# Discord js Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hey I have a little problem.

I wan't to assign a discord role when the bot starts up
I wan't it to work with id's like user id and role id but it is saying
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Thanks in advance Neo

My intents are enabled on discord developer portal

```
const client = new Client({
```

intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS],
}); // intents stuff

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjgdZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guild should not be a variable as it is going to change. Roles need to be fetched from the cache. And then once you have defined `guild` you can use it without defining it again. Try the code below and you should be good.

```js
client.on('ready' async () => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('976862525801000960')
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get('978375133649592361')
    const member = await guild.members.cache.get('404645579705024523')
    
    member.roles.add(role).then(
        console.log(`TOKEN: `)
    )
```

Comment: Please go to https://discord.dev and under your application > bot > make sure that SERVER MEMBERS INTENT is turned on and also please update your question with your client intents `const client = new Client({ intents: \\your intents})`

Comment: Updated answer, let me know what that does

Comment: member is still undefined member is not undefined when is use guild.members.fetch('404645579705024523') but than add is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use async/await for getting user from guild. Use `get()` instead of `fetch()` that's probably gonna solve your problem.

Comment: Hey i putted get instead of fetch but it gives error 
client.guilds.cache.get(...).members.get is not a function

Comment: members.cache.get()

Comment: now it is undefined 
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Comment: Send your last code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gh0st  Fixed it by doing this.

```
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('976862525801000960')
  const role = guild.roles.cache.get('978375133649592361')
  const member =  await guild.members.fetch('404645579705024523')

  member.roles.add(role).then( 
      console.log(`TOKEN: `) 
  )
```